# Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object

Tags: matlab, loops

I want to create a loop to delete file within specific file size and I have these problems.

```
selpath = uigetdir(files) 
for ii = 1:length(files)
    if files(ii).bytes<500000   % 500kb
        delete(fullfile(files(ii).folder, files(ii).name))
    end
end
```

and I always got this message

```
>> cobayginibro

selpath =

    'D:\Proyekan Tes'

Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in cobayginibro (line 3)
    if files(ii).bytes<500000   % 500kb
```

Any idea how to solve this?
Also I want to fprint how many files i've deleted
Thanks before

Comment: What is `files` and how is it set?

Comment: ah sorry, I want the files to be choosen from the selpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `files` after getting `selpath`.

```matlab
selpath = uigetdir() 
files = dir(selpath)
for ii = 1:length(files)
    if ~files(ii).isdir && files(ii).bytes<500000   % 500kb
        delete(fullfile(files(ii).folder, files(ii).name))
    end
end
```

Comment: I considered adding a check for `files(ii).isdir`, but directories have a size of 0 bytes anyway